# Barcode implementation on product items

Tags: barcode, barcode-scanner, barcode-printing

I have a product multiple items, i want to put barcode on them as it is required to sale them in local markete in Pakistan. For this reason i searched on internet to have solutions and i am still a little confused in it. Note: purpose is to sale my product in a local markete and they tell me to put barcode on it.

> Do i really have to register my product with GS1 pk to get barcode
> number?

Through internet search i found a software named `Really Simple Barcode` it make some barcode but not very attractive and also ask me about GS1 barcode number.
There is another mobile app named `QuickMart` is an excellent app to scan different kind of barcode images and also create QR code for free. but i think that's also not what i need.

> What kind of barcode i actually need for selling my product in local
> markete? codebar is suitable or not?
>
> Do i need only one barcode image which will b placed on all the itmes
> of similar product? or i need to have separate barcode image for every
> single item of a single product?
>
> Tell me if there is any way to avoid GS1 registration?
>
> Once i will get my barcode image ready, then how to place it on my
> product? any simple and effective method?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Do I really have to register my product with GS1 pk to get barcode number?
```

Yes. GS1 owns the numbers. Each GS1 office has its own rules but generally you need to join GS1 
to obtain the numbers. They issue you with a set of numbers which you allocate to products as you need them. It has to be co-ordinated by a central authority (GS1) - same as car registration.

```
What kind of barcode do I actually need for selling my product in local markete? Is codebar suitable or not?
```

EAN/UPC 13-digit product code. Using GS1 Databar is not suitable. All systems in use nowadays world-wide are supposed to be able to read EAN/UPC 13-digit codes. If you produce your codes using any other standard, the equipment at the end-user sales location *may* not be able to read the code you are using.

```
Do I need only one barcode image which will b placed on all the itmes of similar product? or i need to have separate barcode image for every single item of a single product?
```

If you produce a million `400g can of beans in tomato sauce` then each one will carry the same barcode number. If you produce `400g can of beans in worcester sauce` then each one of those  will carry another barcode number - it will be a different number from the barcode printed on your `400g can of beans in tomato sauce` as it is a different product. Every `825g can of beans in tomato sauce` you produce will carry a third number because it is a different *size* even if it is the same *fundamental* product.

```
Tell me if there is any way to avoid GS1 registration?
```

You can't avoid GS1 registration in some form. Some administrations will allow a single barcode number or a small set to be issued to a small manufacturer. Best idea is to telephone GS1 ( +92 21 2628213 in Karachi) and ask them. I have heard that they don't bite.

```
Once i will get my barcode image ready, then how to place it on my product? any simple and effective method?
```

GS1 can advise - it's their job and mission. Your label manufacturer will be familiar with the routine and can guide. All you need to do is worry about location on your product. Black bars on a white background are best, but other colour combinations are possible (and some are prohibited because the scanner equipment has difficulty reading the code.) GS1 can advise - it's their job and mission (I may have said that before.) GS1 will often want you to provide them with a sample of your proposed label for verification and will normally allow you a number of verifications as part of your membership. Again, they will advise what needs to be changed about your label if it has to be modified for any reason.

If you are producing individual labels using a barcode printer, then printing the barcodes is incorporated into the basic functionality of the printer. From there, it depends on whether you are constructing your labels by using the Printer Control Language for your printer (with which you should be familiar) or whether you are using label-designer software where you can no doubt simply drop a barcode onto your form in the same way as any text or graphic.

Tips: Look a similarly-shaped products already on the market for how to arrange your label. For instance, on small cans with a small circumference (like soft-drink cans,) the bars are probably best rotated so that the code is horizontal.

Comment: thanks, that's really helpful information to me.. i have few more questions related to this.

Comment: 'how can we check if any existing product using GS1 registered barcode image or not? because i guess there are many fake product manufacturer exist in our society. ' and 'As this is not the law to put barcode on your products, can using fake barcode image do cause any legal consequences? ' and 'Do we also need to register the QR images? whats the difference in my scenario if i use QR images and whats ur recomendation? '

Comment: The codes are owned by and copyrighted to GS1. GS1 will be able to take action against any unauthorised use of *their* codes. They license you to use the codes that they assign to you. You do not **have** to apply barcodes to your products but many vendors will not accept your products for sale if you do not, **especially** the larger vendors (with the biggest sales.) If you use some other manufacturer's barcodes then the vendors will sell your product as the legitimate manufacturer's, at their price, not yours and track inventory on their item, not yours. QR codes - ask GS1.